# Unable to get the user defined variables in JMETER through java

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jmeter, jmeter-plugins

I am new to jmeter and I created a new column in agregate report for it. Now I need to place the values in it with some logic based on User Defined variables.

[image: Here is the image for adding user defined variables]

Now I wanted to  know how to get these variable in `StatGraphVisualizer`.

This is the open source code. Please do the need full for solving this issue and you can get the code from [here](http://jmeter.apache.org/download_jmeter.cgi).

Please find the screen shots for it below.
[image]

Comment: Can you explain why you need to do this ? and what are you aiming at ? thanks

Comment: @ubik load pack This is the performance tool and we are adding a new column into one of the report in jmeter i.e. Aggregate Report and we need to write the logic based on the user defined variables....

Comment: It is the open source code, so if someone is aware of that please let me know. I can give money for the work

Comment: heh, you'd think someone with 1.6K rep would know how this site works.

Answer (score 0):

You can "tell" JMeter to store your User Defined Variables in .jtl results file by setting `sample_variables` property in *user.properties* file (lives under /bin folder of your JMeter installation) as:

```
sample_variables=234,3
```

JMeter restart is required to pick the properties up.

After test execution completion you will be able to see your User Defined Variables values in .jtl file and analyze result with MS Excel, LibreOffice Calc or equivalent.

See [Apache JMeter Properties Customization Guide](https://blazemeter.com/blog/apache-jmeter-properties-customization) for more information on JMeter properties and what can be done through them.

Comment: Thanks for answering.. Its too difficult to understand those docs.. Do you know any easy path to get it

Comment: Easy path has been provided, just use `sample_variables` approach